# I need to combine a list of data frames using bind_row, however, I got the message below; I do not understand the error

Tags: r

data01 <- bind_rows (list_all, .id = "id")
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `Introduction$...12` <datetime> and `GROSS OUTPUT$...12` .
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> data01 <- bind_rows (list_all)
> Error in `bind_rows()`:
> ! Can't combine `..1$...12` <datetime> and `..3$...12` .
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
> <error/vctrs_error_incompatible_type>
> Error in `bind_rows()`:
> ! Can't combine `..1$...12` <datetime> and `..3$...12` .

---

Backtrace:

1. dplyr::bind_rows(list_all)
2. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
   Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

> rlang::last_trace()
> <error/vctrs_error_incompatible_type>
> Error in `bind_rows()`:
> ! Can't combine `..1$...12` <datetime> and `..3$...12` .

---

Backtrace:
▆

1. └─dplyr::bind_rows(list_all)
2. ├─dplyr:::fix_call(vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id))
3. │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
4. └─vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
5. ```
   └─vctrs `<fn>`()
   ```
6. ```
     └─vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
   ```
7. ```
       └─vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
   ```
8. ```
         └─vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
   ```
9. ```
           └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
   ```
10. ```
              └─rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = vctrs_error_call(call))
    ```

Comment: give the data also and not just the error

Comment: I suspect both data sets have no header in the 12th column, `bind_rows` is trying to combine them, but they have different data types. I suggest renaming the column before you combine.

Comment: Thank you guys. my data is an excel file with multiple sheets. For example, the introduction sheet contains several columns such as site code, sine name, sowing date... and other sheets are yield, flowering time and so on for each site and different varieties.. ..

Comment: @onyambu and @Jon Spring here is my `code`

Comment: You dont have the data.

Comment: path <- "D:/Files/Agriculture Project/data/2003/"

setwd(path)

sheet_names <- readxl::excel_sheets("Full Harvest Results_2003.xls") # get sheet names


# using lapply import data to R

list_all <- lapply (sheet_names, function (x){
  as.data.frame(read_excel("Full Harvest Results_2003.xls", sheet = x))
})

list_all # print data

# rename based on the sheet names
names (list_all) <- sheet_names

head (list_all$Introduction)


# combine all in one

data01 <- rbind (list_all) ## I have tried bind_row function as well, but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the column may be different for different data frames. May be int for one data frame and character for another.